# Delete Child ChartObjects with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I cannot figure out how to delete charts with VBA.

Starting Point:

1. Create Blank Workbook
2. Press F11 three times to create `Chart1`, `Chart2`, and `Chart3`
3. Right-click in `Chart2`, Move Chart, Object in: `Chart 1`
4. Right-click in `Chart3`, Move Chart, Object in: `Chart 1`

What VBA code will delete all charts (`Chart2` and `Chart3`) from `Chart1`?

Attempts:

```
'Try 1: Run-time error -2147024809 (80070057):
'        The specified value is out of range.
Sheets("Chart1").ChartObjects.Delete

'Try 2: (Same error)
Charts("Chart1").ChartObjects.Delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can't delete that charts. The reason is that chart is locked and it's not possible to unlock it from neither VBA nor Application.

The only workaround I've figured out is to: 1. move it to any worksheet, 2. delete it.

Possible code could be as follows:

```
Dim myCHART As Chart
Set myCHART = Sheets("Chart1")


myCHART.ChartObjects(1).Select
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=Worksheets(1).Name
Worksheets(1).Shapes(Worksheets(1).Shapes.Count).Delete
```

Updated code: (by Steven)

```
Do While Charts("Chart1").ChartObjects.Count > 0
    Charts("Chart1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, _
                                                    Worksheets(1).Name
    Worksheets(1).Shapes(Worksheets(1).Shapes.Count).Delete
Loop
```

Comment: As suggested, I could delete the `Chart` moving it to another `Worksheet`.  I edited your answer to include my code sample (based on your suggestion).  Thank you!